# Laravel 5.7 giving error 500 on localhost

Tags: laravel-5

I have recently installed laravel 5.7 on my machine but its giving me a 500 error but at tje same time i have anothe laravel 5.6 app which is working on the same server. What could be the problem. I am working on a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Did you see at your server logs to see what the error 500 actually is?

1) Go to your Laravel logs `(app/storage/logs)` and see if the error is contained in there.

2)Yo can just debugging add a `die('hi')` command at the start of your `routes` file and then find out where is the error

3) I added the following to the `public/index.php` on my cause it helped me

```
try {
    $app->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```